# Can't save the file «/usr/share/netbeans/10.0/etc/netbeans.conf»?

Tags: netbeans, java

I am trying to change the `jdk` access path in the `netbeans.conf` file to solve the `java.lang` file not found problem and I cannot save this file with a new name or the same name, so I cannot solve the problem. It reports to me, `You don't have permission for do that`, how to solve?
I use `linux mint 20 Ulyana`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Netbeans or a connected process is not running. Try completely powering down your system, then start it back up again.
If that does not work, then use the vi editor to edit the file and try putting "sudo" before the command like this:

```
   sudo vi /usr/share/netbeans/10.0/etc/netbeans.conf
```

It may prompt you for your password.
Learning to use vi is an excellent skill.
Always be very careful using sudo. Usually there is a reason why normal users cannot access files and sudo can. So take a back up just in case.

Comment: I solved the problem accessing as a root in the path and the file too, but i unlucky not solved my main problem to access java.lang by this change...

Comment: Logging in as root to solve a problem often makes things worse. How did you install Netbeans in the first place?